# IE Giving Me Problems with Dialog Button

Tags: jquery, dialog

I am getting the following error in IE only and its causing my dialog not to popup.

> Expected identifier, string or number

Here is my code:

```
           $( "#success-popup" ).dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height:560,
                width:665,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "close":{
                        text:'CLICK HERE TO CLOSE THIS WINDOW',
                        class:'big-red',
                        click: function() {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                      }
                }

            });
```

I have read that this is commonly an issue of a misplaced comma but I dont think I have one. Any clue as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `class` is a reserved word in JS (look at the syntax highlighting here) – try putting quotes around it.

Comment: And this problem is just with IE, right?

Comment: What versions of IE, jQuery, and jQuery UI?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the word class is reserved in IE javascript interpretation.  Comment the class and then set the class property after the dialog is set

```
...
//  class:'big-red',
...
```